# Windows10: Windows service not starting

Tags: .net, windows-services, windows-10

When i try to start my windows service in windows 10, i am getting the following error. I copied it from event viewer

```
Faulting application name: MyAppp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56c58165
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632da1c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000bd8a8
Faulting process id: 0x124c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d16afbc8d42334
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Desktop\NightlyBuild\ServiceOutput\MyAppp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 0269d024-55a3-46d6-8f00-d7f99bab4a4a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Is it compiled for x86? If so try to use Any CPU in the target platform setting

Answer (score 0):

0xe0434352 is a generic error code used by the .NET CLR for an unhandled exception. Your code must be throwing an exception from a thread with no exception handler.

Implement an event handler for the AppDomain.UnhandledException event and log the details of the exception from there. Then you'll be able to locate and fix the root cause.